# STEP to SolidWorks Part Conversion - Programatically

Tags: solidworks, solidworksapi

Are there any reference implementations on how to convert a STEP file to a SolidWorks Part file - I came across this one `https://www.engineering.com/tutorials/importing-a-step-file-solidworks/` to convert a SolidWorks part to STEP file but not the otherway around. Please share if you have any inputs on this.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Solidworks will open a STEP file and recognize the geometry as a 'dumb' solid body, meaning the feature tree will be empty. This is enough for most use cases. [Here's](https://help.solidworks.com/2023/english/api/sldworksapi/import_step_file_example_csharp.htm) an example from the Solidworks API help.

If you are specifically asking about creating the feature tree, thats called feature translation. Software does exist, but its limited, and many implementations are custom.